# solving equation involving absolute values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Given the equation

$|x+2| + |3x+6| = 8,$

how can I find the sum of all its roots?

Comment: open absolute value bars $|x+2|=x+2$ if $x+2 \ge 0$

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  I edited the question to improve clarity; let me know if I deviated from your intent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy if you notice that $|3x+6| = 3|x+2|$.

So:

$\begin{align}
|x+2| + |3x+6| &= 8 \\
|x+2| + 3|x+2| &= 8  \\
4|x+2| &= 8 \\
|x+2| &= 2\end{align}$

Can you finish?

Comment: The one is 0 and the other is -4. So the answer is -4. Thanks

Comment: Correct & you're welcome!